# Как сделать правильный запрос к базе phpMyAdmin? Используя "MysqliDb.php" из "www.github.com"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Я работаю с файлом "MysqliDb.php" из "www.github.com".

Вот примеры из него: 
1) 
$db-> where('dentist_id', $dentist_id);
$visitors = $db->get('visitors');   //  подключись к таблице "visitors" и вытащи из него все строки, где поле "dentist_id" = "$dentist_id";

2) 
$db->orderBy("fio","asc");
$dentists=$db->get('dentist'); //  подключись к таблице "dentist" и вытащи из него все строки, при этом сделай сортировку поля "fio" по алфавиту.

Вот только я с ним не до конца разобрался.  Есть таблица (см.фото), мне надо для слайдера на ГЛАВНОЙ странице вытаскивать
из таблицы те строки, где значение поля "number"  самое большое для 1 слайда (в данном случае  "number" = 9), потом для второго слайда строку с предыдущим максимальным значением поля  (в данном случае  "number" = 7) и т.д.

Я могу сделать 5 запросов, но как выставить в них сортировку не могу придумать. Можете подсказать? Спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **$db->orderBy("number","DESC");**

Comment: Вчера думал про этот вариант - думал не сработает! А нет сработало! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

ПОЛНЫЙ РАЗВЕРНУТЫЙ ОТВЕТ (может кому-то пригодится).

```html
<?php
$db->orderBy("number","desc");
$news=$db->get('news');
?>


Вставка в 1 слайд: 
<h4><?php echo $news[0]['opisanie']; ?></h4>   и  
<img src="news/<?php echo $news[0]['photo']; ?>" alt="filler image">

Вставка во 2 слайд: 
<h4><?php echo $news[1]['opisanie']; ?></h4>   и  
<img src="news/<?php echo $news[1]['photo']; ?>" alt="filler image">  и т.д.
```